# How to select lines inwhich the sum of negative numbers in the line is equal or less than -3 (with awk)?

Tags: awk

I have a sample file like this:

```
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210  
AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A 2 -1 2 2 2 -1 -1 2 2 0
AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A 1 2 -1 2 2 -1 2 -1 2 0
```

and I want to exclud the lines that have a sum of negative number equal or less than `-3`, I know how to calculate the sum of negative number and print it, with this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum += $i; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,sum; sum=0}' test.txt > out.txt
```

But I don't want to do this I just want to calculate the sum of negative number and then select the lines that have less or equal to `-3`.

These are the commands that I wrote:

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum += $i;  sum=0}' test.txt | awk 'sum <= -3' > out.txt
```

I get no errors but the out.txt file is empty!

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} NR >=2 {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^-/) sum += $i; if sum >= -3 pritn R; sum=0}' test.txt | wc -l
```

which I get:

```
^ syntax error
```

and how can I make sure that the first line(header) would be also in my output file?
so I would like to have this out put:

```
probeset_id submitted_id chr snp_pos alleleA alleleB 562_201 562_202 562_203 562_204 562_205 562_206 562_207 562_208 562_209 562_210  
    AX-75448119 Chr1_41908741 1 41908741 T C 0 -1 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 -1 
    AX-75448118 Chr1_41908545 1 41908545 T A 2 -1 2 2 2 -1 -1 2 2 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '
  NR == 1 { 
    print 
    next 
  } 
  { 
    negsum=0 
    for(i=7; i<=NF; i++) { 
      if ($i<0) {
        negsum += $i 
      } 
  } 
  negsum <= -3'
```

Your first try fails because you use two different invocations of awk. These are two different  programs being run, and the second knows nothing about the `sum` variable in the first, so it uses the default value `sum = 0`.

The second try just has a mis-spelling. You used `pritn` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 2):

What you described can be easier to code with proper formatting. (Not that I'd always resort to using editor when scripting `awk`...)

The first condition (`NR == 1`) just ensures we print the first line as is.

```
awk '
NR == 1 { print }
NR >= 2 {
    sum = 0;
    for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i < 0)
            sum += $i;
    }
    if (sum <= -3)
        print;
}
' test.txt > out.txt
```